# What are the differences between returning values and side effect coding?

Tags: java, c++

My questions are motivated by a C++ code which is not mine and that I am currently trying to understand. Nevertheless, I think this question can be answered by OO developers in general (because I have ever seen this case in Java code for example).

Reading through the code, I noticed that the developer always work using side effects (most functions have "void return type" except for getters and some rare cases) instead of returning results directly. He sometimes uses return values but only for control flows (error code... instead of exceptions).

Here are two possible examples of his prototypes (in pseudo-code):
For a function that should return min, max and avg of the float values in a matrix M:

```
void computeStatistics(float min, float max, float avg, Matrix M);
```

OR

```
void computeStatistics(List myStat, Matrix M);
```

For a function that should return some objects in a given list that verifies a certain criteria and the number of objects found:

```
int controlValue findObjects(List result, int nbObjectsFound, Object myCriteria, List givenList)
```

I am not familiar with C++ as you can probably see in my very-pseudo-code... But rather with Matlab where it is possible to return everything you want from a function for example an int and a List side by side (which could be useful for the second example). I know it is not possible in C++ and that could explain the second prototype but it doesn't explain the choice for the first example where he could have done:

```
List myStat computeStat(Matrix M)
```

Finally, here are my questions:
What are the possible reasons that could motivate this choice? Is it a good practice, a convention or just a development choice? Are there advantages of one way over the other (returning values vs. side effects way)?

Comment: A function that takes some arguments that it does not mutate, and returns a new object, is semantically clearer than one that takes many arguments, and mutates some of them. But sometimes you do need to modify an existing object. So it all depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Note that there is usually no penalty for returning a large object by value in C++, so the clean solution is also efficient.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of C++:

IMO using returns values is clearer than passing value by references and present, in most cases, no overhead. (please have a look at [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision))

However if you do use return values for your control flow, using references is not a bad thing and is still clear for most developers.

So I guess we could say that the choice is yours.

Keep also in mind that many developers are not aware of what black magic your C++ compiler is doing and so using return values might offend them.

Answer (score 1):

In the past it was a common practice to use reference parameters as output, since returning complex objects was very slow without return value optimization an move semantic. Today I belief in most cases returning the value is the best choice.

[Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Answer (score 1):

Writing the following provided that the list has a copy would by me be considered inappropriate.

```
void computeStatistics(List myStat, Matrix M);
```

Instead (provided that list has copy) you should.

```
List myStat computeStat(Matrix M)
```

However the call-by-reference approach can be motivated if you do not have a copy on your object, then you wont need to allocate it on the heap instead you can allocate it on the stack and send your function a pointer to it.

Regarding:

```
void computeStatistics(float min, float max, float avg, Matrix M);
```

My personal opinion is that best-practice is one method one purpose, so I would do this like:

```
float min computeMin(Matrix M);
float max computeMax(Matrix M);
float avg computeAvg(Matrix M);
```

The only reason that I can see for making all this in one function would be because the calculations are not done separately (more work to do it in separate functions).

If you however need to have several return types in one method i would do it with call-by-reference. For example:

```
void SomeMethod(input1, input2, &output1, &output2, &output3)
```

Comment: You should probably specify which language you are talking about. What you say at the beginning does not apply to C++. The list does not have to be allocated on any heap.

Comment: Provided that the list have a copy. What i wrote applies better on classes that does not have  a copy..

Comment: "With the second approach you would need to allocate the list on the heap", that is simply not true, unless you specify that the type is not copyable or movable, which you haven't done. Container and matrix types are usually copyable, so your statement is quite misleading.

Comment: @juanchopanza Made an edit, hope its not still as missleading!

Comment: Yes, that is less misleading. The main motivation to pass references in my view is when you really want to make a modification on an existing object (i.e. append something to a list, sort a container etc.)